# Opening eclipse project from subversion (Subversive, local repository)

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I have the project in my local repository. Repository survived disk format, however eclipse didnt. So what I'm trying to do is opening an existing in repository project and I can't do that using Import/Project from SVN since it seems only to accept www path

I can't create repository in place of an old one aswell. What should I do?

Comment: Did you try typing file://etc in the URL text box when creating a new repository in Eclipse?

Comment: The uppermost level folder of your Subversion repository.

Comment: pls post it as an answer since you just solved my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `file://etc` in the URL text box when creating a new repository in Eclipse.

[image]